# Rails 4 has_many association not working when model has 2 subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.

I have an Anomaly Records class called Ar that inherits from the following classes as follows:

```
class RecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class ArAndEcrBase < RecordBase
  self.abstract_class = true

  # Relations
  belongs_to :originator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'originator_id'
  has_many :attachments
end

class Ar < ArAndEcrBase

end
```

I want to share some relations with a class that handles another type of records in the Ar subclass however the has_many relationship doesn't work.

The following works:

```
> Ar.last.originator 
=> #<User id: 1, ...
```

The following crashes:

```
> Ar.last.attachments
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'attachments.ar_and_ecr_base_id'
```

For some reason the has_many relationship doesn't work well. It should look for column *attachments.ar_id* and not *attachments.ar_and_ecr_base_id*

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a Rails bug?

Atm the only way to get the code working is to move the has_many relation to the Ar class:

```
class Ar < ArAndEcrBase
  has_many :attachments    
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `inverse_of` option?

Comment: Hi Rocco! had never heard of that option. Tried setting it but it didn't work. I got the exact same error Thanks anyway!

Comment: Atm the only way to get the code working is to move the has_many relation to the Ar class:

Comment: I guess this must be a Rails bug then!

Answer (score 0):

If you want several models to have association to the same other model you probably need a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Comment: Hi! I don't want a polymorphic association. Note that the first two classes are not associated to any table: self.abstract_class = true, only the Ar class actually has a table. Thx for the feedback though!